# How to remove white spaces and capitalize every first letter in the string in the robotramework

Tags: string, selenium, robotframework

How can I remove white spaces and capitalize every first letter in the string in the robotframework, so later I use the result in the Selenium library calls?

**Test to Unlock the Service Account:**

```
  Open Browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}
  ${string_1} =      get text    ${question_1}
  ${temp_answer} =   set variable     ${string_1}.title()
  ${answer}=  evaluate       ${string_1}.replace(" ","")
  Input Text    ${Answer_1}    ${answer}
  sleep    5s
```

**Input:**

```
Legal business name
```

**Output:**

```
LegalBusinessName?
```

Comment: Are you interested in answers that require you create a python keyword, or must the solution only include robot keywords?

Answer (score 1):

You were close to achieving it, but made two crucial mistakes. The first one is you used `Set Variable` and tried calling the python's `title()` string method in the argument - but that doesn't work for the keyword. It is a straightforward assignment - synonymous to the `=` operator; so what you ended up with as value was the string "Legal business name.title()". You should use the `Evaluate` keyword like in the second call, which does python's code eval.

The other mistake was to use two different variables - you store the capitalized version in the var `${temp_answer}`, but then you don't remove the whitespace from it, but from the original one - `${string_1}`. So even if the capitalization worked, you still wouldn't get the desired end result in the `${answer}` var.

Here's a one-liner how to achieve what you need:

```
${answer}=    evaluate       """${string_1}""".title().replace(" ","")
```

The 2 methods are chained - `replace()` works on the result of `title()`, and the value of `string_1` is in triple quotes so python works with its sting representation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed this issue by writing python code